swiperjs left/right tap/click
swiperjs has a ton of options, but I can't tell if it has the one I'm looking for.
I have a (default) swiper where only one image is visible at a time. I can swipe left and right to change slides (default behavior). But I also want to be able to click/tap on the right half of the slide to go to the next side, or click/tap on the left half of the slide to go to the previous slide. Is there some option to make this happen, or do I have to do some custom event handling? (I think the slideToClickedSlide option is for when you have more than one slide shown at a time.)

You could simply use the default prev/next buttons - and style them, so that they cover half of the image each. Probably best / easiest done using absolute positioning - and then making their background / text content transparent. Or you use your own elements, and give them a click handler to call the appropriate API methods (slidePrev / slideNext)

Based on C3roe's comment, here is what worked. I didn't have to add new elements, just a click handler on the swiper's containing div. My incorrect assumption was that handling clicks on the slider container might interfere with swiper's drag behavior, which is why I asked this question.
let mySwiper =
    new Swiper(
        ".SwiperContainer",
        {
            loop: false,
            longSwipesRatio: 0.1,
            pagination:
            {
                el: ".swiper-pagination"
            },
            keyboard:
            {
                enabled: true
            },
        }
    );

...

$( ".SwiperContainer" ).on( "click", HandleSwiperClick );

...

function HandleSwiperClick( e )
{
    let w = $( ".SwiperContainer" ).width();
    if ( e.offsetX < ( w / 2 ) )
    {
        mySwiper.slidePrev();
    }
    else
    {
        mySwiper.slideNext();
    }
}

